# Shiny with three inputs of selecting variable, its levels and adding other columns

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, render

From the code, renderUI in server is disconnected to the main variable selection, so as print textOutput() to main pannel.

I'm trying to build a shiny app has three inputs at the sidebar of

1. selecting a main variable
2. the levels of the selected main variable to choose(multiple)
3. options of adding columns, and then print selected data at the main panel

for example, with iris,

1. I choose Species
2. level should show  options of "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" but ***which is not showing***
3. I can add other columns
   **But the selected rows and columns are not printed at the main panel**

```
data <- iris


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Data selection"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("show_vars", "Main column:",
                     choices = colnames(data), multiple = FALSE),
      uiOutput("category1"),
      selectInput("add_col", "Add columns to display", names(data), multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("selected")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$category1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat1', 'Levels from main column', choices = levels(input$show_vars), multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  
  df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1,{
    columns = names(data)
    if(input$cat1=="All") {df_subset <- data}
    else{df_subset <- data[data$Category1 == input$cat1, columns]}
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderText({ df_subset() })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `choices =c("All",  levels(data[,input$show_vars]))`

Comment: It's better to replace `renderText` by `renderTable` and `textOutput` by `tableOutput`

Comment: @HubertL, I guess we were both looking at the same question at the same time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
data <- iris


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Data selection"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("show_vars", "Main column:",
                     choices = colnames(data), multiple = FALSE),
      uiOutput("category1"),
      selectInput("add_col", "Add columns to display", names(data), multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("selected")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$category1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$show_vars)
    selectInput('cat1', 'Levels from main column', choices = c('All',levels(data[,input$show_vars])), multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  
  df_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$cat1,input$add_col)
    columns <-  names(data) %in% input$add_col
    if(input$cat1=="All") {dfsubset <- data[,columns]}
    else {dfsubset <- data[data[,input$show_vars] == input$cat1, columns]}
    dfsubset <- as.data.frame(dfsubset)
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderDT({ df_subset() })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]